# Google Forms: Accepts forms with a specific sum of numeric fields

Tags: google-forms

I am building a voting lottery form for my friends. Each participant should guess the number of seats that every party will gain in the upcoming Israeli elections.

[image]

Each party is a required field, and the numerical value is verified in the inclusive (0, 120) range.

Since there are total of 120 seats in the *Knesset*, so I would like to enable form submission only if the sum of numbers equals 120.

**Is there a way to enable form submission based on the sum of numerical values in the form?**